# Передача данных на порт по протоколу модбас

Tags: unity3d, modbus

Проблема в том, что данные не передаются на порт. В чем может быть проблема? Через Form передаются данные и проблема не в данных, а в передаче.в логе расписано все.

```
static String debugPath = "debug.log";
static int debSrc = 1;
private bool debugRun = true;
//public bool debugOneRound { get; set; }

static readonly int rTimeout = 25;
static readonly int wTimeout = 20;

static readonly ushort[] crc16Table = new ushort[]
{
    0x0000, 0xC1C0, 0x81C1, 0x4001, 0x01C3, 0xC003, 0x8002, 0x41C2,
    0x01C6, 0xC006, 0x8007, 0x41C7, 0x0005, 0xC1C5, 0x81C4, 0x4004,
    0x01CC, 0xC00C, 0x800D, 0x41CD, 0x000F, 0xC1CF, 0x81CE, 0x400E,
    0x000A, 0xC1CA, 0x81CB, 0x400B, 0x01C9, 0xC009, 0x8008, 0x41C8,
    0x01D8, 0xC018, 0x8019, 0x41D9, 0x001B, 0xC1DB, 0x81DA, 0x401A,
    0x001E, 0xC1DE, 0x81DF, 0x401F, 0x01DD, 0xC01D, 0x801C, 0x41DC,
    0x0014, 0xC1D4, 0x81D5, 0x4015, 0x01D7, 0xC017, 0x8016, 0x41D6,
    0x01D2, 0xC012, 0x8013, 0x41D3, 0x0011, 0xC1D1, 0x81D0, 0x4010,
    0x01F0, 0xC030, 0x8031, 0x41F1, 0x0033, 0xC1F3, 0x81F2, 0x4032,
    0x0036, 0xC1F6, 0x81F7, 0x4037, 0x01F5, 0xC035, 0x8034, 0x41F4,
    0x003C, 0xC1FC, 0x81FD, 0x403D, 0x01FF, 0xC03F, 0x803E, 0x41FE,
    0x01FA, 0xC03A, 0x803B, 0x41FB, 0x0039, 0xC1F9, 0x81F8, 0x4038,
    0x0028, 0xC1E8, 0x81E9, 0x4029, 0x01EB, 0xC02B, 0x802A, 0x41EA,
    0x01EE, 0xC02E, 0x802F, 0x41EF, 0x002D, 0xC1ED, 0x81EC, 0x402C,
    0x01E4, 0xC024, 0x8025, 0x41E5, 0x0027, 0xC1E7, 0x81E6, 0x4026,
    0x0022, 0xC1E2, 0x81E3, 0x4023, 0x01E1, 0xC021, 0x8020, 0x41E0,
    0x01A0, 0xC060, 0x8061, 0x41A1, 0x0063, 0xC1A3, 0x81A2, 0x4062,
    0x0066, 0xC1A6, 0x81A7, 0x4067, 0x01A5, 0xC065, 0x8064, 0x41A4,
    0x006C, 0xC1AC, 0x81AD, 0x406D, 0x01AF, 0xC06F, 0x806E, 0x41AE,
    0x01AA, 0xC06A, 0x806B, 0x41AB, 0x0069, 0xC1A9, 0x81A8, 0x4068,
    0x0078, 0xC1B8, 0x81B9, 0x4079, 0x01BB, 0xC07B, 0x807A, 0x41BA,
    0x01BE, 0xC07E, 0x807F, 0x41BF, 0x007D, 0xC1BD, 0x81BC, 0x407C,
    0x01B4, 0xC074, 0x8075, 0x41B5, 0x0077, 0xC1B7, 0x81B6, 0x4076,
    0x0072, 0xC1B2, 0x81B3, 0x4073, 0x01B1, 0xC071, 0x8070, 0x41B0,
    0x0050, 0xC190, 0x8191, 0x4051, 0x0193, 0xC053, 0x8052, 0x4192,
    0x0196, 0xC056, 0x8057, 0x4197, 0x0055, 0xC195, 0x8194, 0x4054,
    0x019C, 0xC05C, 0x805D, 0x419D, 0x005F, 0xC19F, 0x819E, 0x405E,
    0x005A, 0xC19A, 0x819B, 0x405B, 0x0199, 0xC059, 0x8058, 0x4198,
    0x0188, 0xC048, 0x8049, 0x4189, 0x004B, 0xC18B, 0x818A, 0x404A,
    0x004E, 0xC18E, 0x818F, 0x404F, 0x018D, 0xC04D, 0x804C, 0x418C,
    0x0044, 0xC184, 0x8185, 0x4045, 0x0187, 0xC047, 0x8046, 0x4186,
    0x0182, 0xC042, 0x8043, 0x4183, 0x0041, 0xC181, 0x8180, 0x4040
};

public enum Error { OK, NOSERIAL, IOERROR, NOMODBUS };
public Error error { get; set; }

private enum EState { NULL, SER, CONN };
private EState state;
static bool _exit;

static String sname = "COM3";

static Thread mbThread;

// unlatched vars;
// fighter's seat
private bool seatChanged = false;
//private int seatNRecv=0;
public bool seatOnline { get; private set; }
private uint seatControl;
public uint SeatControl { get { return seatControl; } set { seatControl = value; if (!seatChanged) seatChanged = true; } }
public uint seatPins { get; private set; }

// pannel
//private int pannelNRecv=0;
private bool pannelChanged = false;
public bool pannelOnline { get; private set; }
private uint speed = 0;
public uint Speed { get { return speed; } set { speed = value; tlog("pan.spd"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }
private uint angle = 3;
public uint Angle { get { return angle; } set { angle = value; tlog("pan.angle"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }
private uint compass = 1;
public uint Compass { get { return compass; } set { compass = value; tlog("pan.compass"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }
private uint fuel = 0;
public uint Fuel { get { return fuel; } set { fuel = value; tlog("pan.fuel"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }
private uint year = 1905;
public uint Year { get { return year; } set { year = value; tlog("pan.year"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }
private byte month = 1;
public byte Month { get { return month; } set { month = value; tlog("pan.month"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }
public byte day = 25;
public byte Day { get { return day; } set { day = value; tlog("pan.day"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }
private byte hour = 13;
public byte Hour { get { return hour; } set { hour = value; tlog("pan.hour"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }
private byte minute = 15;
public byte Minute { get { return minute; } set { minute = value; tlog("pan.minute"); if (!pannelChanged) pannelChanged = true; } }

// force shields
//private int shieldsNRecv=0;
private bool shieldsChanged = false;
public bool shieldsOnline { get; private set; }
private uint fshields;
public uint FShields { get { return fshields; } set { fshields = value; if (!shieldsChanged) shieldsChanged = true; } }
private bool fInd;
public bool FInd { get { return fInd; } set { fInd = value; if (!shieldsChanged) shieldsChanged = true; } }

// indicator
//private int heightNRecv=0;
private bool heightChanged = false;
public bool heightOnline { get; private set; }
private uint height;
public uint Height { get { return height; } set { height = value; if (!heightChanged) heightChanged = true; } }
private bool hInd;
public bool HInd { get { return hInd; } set { hInd = value; if (!heightChanged) heightChanged = true; } }

// control board
//private int modNRecv=0;
private bool modChanged = false;
public bool modOnline { get; private set; }
private bool meh01;
public bool MEH01 { get { return meh01; } set { meh01 = value; if (!modChanged) modChanged = true; } }
private bool meh02;
public bool MEH02 { get { return meh02; } set { meh02 = value; if (!modChanged) modChanged = true; } }
private bool end01;
public bool END01 { get { return end01; } set { end01 = value; if (!modChanged) modChanged = true; } }

// latched registers
private byte[] seatwArr = { 0x04, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // 8
private const byte seatwRecLen = 0x08;
private byte[] seatrArr = { 0x04, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0, 0 }; // 8
private const byte seatrRecLen = 0x07;
private byte[] pannelArr = { 0x05, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x12, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
private const byte panRecLen = 0x08;
private byte[] shieldsArr = { 0x06, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
private const byte shieldsRecLen = 0x08;
private byte[] heightArr = { 0x07, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x04, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // 13
private const byte heightRecLen = 0x08;
private byte[] moduleArr = { 0x08, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x06, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }; // 15
private const byte moduleRecLen = 0x08;

private byte[] recvArr = new byte[256];
private int nrecv;





public static ushort CRC16(byte[] bytes, int len)
{
    ushort crc = 0xFFFF;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
        crc = (ushort)((crc << 8) ^ crc16Table[(crc >> 8) ^ bytes[i]]);
    return crc;
}

public dirijable1()
{
    tlog("######################################## Dirijable ready.");
    this.state = EState.NULL;
    seatrLatch(); // it's lazy for me to find right crc values and write it there
}

~dirijable1()
{
    //Stop();
    return;
}


public void Start()
{
    //sname = s;
    tlog("######################################## Dirijable Launched!!!");
    tlog("Serial port name: " + sname);
    //debugRun = true;
    //_exit = false;
    //Thread.Sleep(10);
    //mbThread = new Thread(mbLoop);
    //mbThread.Start();
    this.state = EState.SER;

    StartCoroutine(_mbLoop());
    InvokeRepeating("mbSendRecv", 5, 5);
}
public void R()
{
    compass++;
}
public void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    tlog("Stop Dirijable");
    //if (_exit == true) return;
    //if (state != EState.SER) return;
    //Thread.Sleep(10);
    _exit = true;
    //mbThread.Join();
    //Thread.Sleep(50);
    tlog("Dirijable stopped");
}





private int mbSendRecv(byte[] arr, bool doWait = true)
{
    int nrcv;
    ushort crc;

    SerialPort ser = new SerialPort(sname, 9600);

    // setup & open serial port
    tlog("setuport");
    ser.ReadTimeout = (int)rTimeout;
    ser.WriteTimeout = (int)wTimeout;
    try { ser.Open(); }
    catch
    {
        error = Error.NOSERIAL;
        if (debugRun) tlog("Can't open serial");
        return -1;
    }
    tlog("wr");
    // write sequence
    if (debugRun) tlog(arr, arr.Length, 0);
    ser.ReadExisting(); // flush input buffer
    ser.Write(arr, 0, arr.Length);
    while (ser.BytesToWrite != 0) ;
    Thread.Sleep(5);
    nrcv = 0;
    // read sequence
    if (doWait)
    {
        tlog("rd");
        recvArr.Initialize();
        while (nrcv < recvArr.Length)
        {
            int btr = ser.BytesToRead;
            if (btr == 0) btr = 1;
            if (btr + nrcv > recvArr.Length) btr = recvArr.Length - nrcv; // trunc received bytes to buffer size
            try { nrcv += ser.Read(recvArr, nrcv, btr); }
            catch (TimeoutException)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (debugRun)
            tlog(recvArr, nrcv, 1);
        if (nrecv > 2)
        {
            crc = CRC16(recvArr, nrecv - 2);
            if ((crc >> 8 != recvArr[nrecv - 2]) || ((crc & 0xff) != recvArr[nrecv - 1]))
                if (debugRun) tlog("CRC error: 0x" + crc.ToString("X4"));
        }
    }
    // TODO: check received crc

    ser.Close();
    ser.Dispose();

    return nrcv;
}

IEnumerator _mbLoop()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (this.state != EState.SER) continue;

        if (pannelChanged)
        {
            panelLatch();
            nrecv = mbSendRecv(pannelArr, false);
            tlog("nrecv = " + nrecv.ToString());
            if (nrecv != panRecLen) pannelOnline = false; else pannelOnline = true;
            pannelChanged = false;
        }

        if (shieldsChanged)
        {
            shieldsLatch();
            nrecv = mbSendRecv(shieldsArr, false);
            if (nrecv != shieldsRecLen) shieldsOnline = false; else shieldsOnline = true;
            shieldsChanged = false;
        }

        if (seatChanged)
        {
            seatwLatch();
            nrecv = mbSendRecv(seatwArr, false);
            if (nrecv != seatwRecLen) seatOnline = false; else seatOnline = true;
            seatChanged = false;
        }

        if (heightChanged)
        {
            heightLatch();
            nrecv = mbSendRecv(heightArr, false);
            if (nrecv != heightRecLen) heightOnline = false; else heightOnline = true;
            heightChanged = false;
        }

        if (modChanged)
        {
            moduleLatch();
            nrecv = mbSendRecv(moduleArr, false);
            if (nrecv != moduleRecLen) modOnline = false; else modOnline = true;
            modChanged = false;
        }

        if (seatChanged)
        {
            seatwLatch();
            nrecv = mbSendRecv(seatwArr, false);
            if (nrecv != seatwRecLen) seatOnline = false; else seatOnline = true;
            seatChanged = false;
        }
        yield return null;
        //debugRun = debugOneRound;
        //debugOneRound = false;

    }
}

// calc crc for internal packet buffer to send and write at the tail of buffer

private void panelLatch()
{
    // latch param for pannel
    if (debugRun) tlog("panel param latch");
    pannelArr[7] = 0x00; pannelArr[8] = (byte)(speed & 0x7f); //0x00 speed 
                                                              // 0x01 umused
    pannelArr[11] = 0x00; pannelArr[12] = (byte)(angle % 6);// 0x02 angle 1-5
    pannelArr[13] = 0x00; pannelArr[14] = (byte)(compass % 17); // 0x03 compass 1-16
    pannelArr[15] = 0x00; pannelArr[16] = (byte)(fuel % 101); // 0x04 fuel 0-100
                                                              // 0x05 unused
    pannelArr[19] = (byte)(year >> 8); pannelArr[20] = (byte)(year & 0xff); // 0x06 year 0-9999
    ushort mmdd = (ushort)((((ushort)(month)) << 8) | ((ushort)(day)));
    pannelArr[21] = (byte)(mmdd >> 8); pannelArr[22] = (byte)(mmdd & 0xff);  // 0x07 mmdd
    ushort hhmm = (ushort)((((ushort)(hour)) << 8) | ((ushort)(minute)));
    pannelArr[23] = (byte)(hhmm >> 8); pannelArr[24] = (byte)(hhmm & 0xff); // 0x08 hhmm
    ushort crc = CRC16(pannelArr, pannelArr.Length - 2);
    pannelArr[25] = (byte)(crc >> 8); pannelArr[26] = (byte)(crc & 0xff);
}

private void shieldsLatch()
{
    if (debugRun) tlog("shields param latch");
    shieldsArr[7] = (byte)(fshields >> 8); shieldsArr[8] = (byte)(fshields & 0xff);
    if (this.fInd) shieldsArr[10] = 1; else shieldsArr[10] = 0;
    ushort crc = CRC16(shieldsArr, shieldsArr.Length - 2);
    shieldsArr[11] = (byte)(crc >> 8); shieldsArr[12] = (byte)(crc & 0xff);
}

private void heightLatch()
{
    if (debugRun) tlog("height param latch");
    heightArr[7] = (byte)(height >> 8); heightArr[8] = (byte)(height & 0xff);
    if (this.hInd) heightArr[10] = 1; else heightArr[10] = 0;
    ushort crc = CRC16(heightArr, heightArr.Length - 2);
    heightArr[11] = (byte)(crc >> 8); heightArr[12] = (byte)(crc & 0xff);
}

private void moduleLatch()
{
    if (debugRun) tlog("module param latch");
    moduleArr[8] = (byte)((this.meh01) ? 1 : 0);
    moduleArr[10] = (byte)((this.meh02) ? 1 : 0);
    moduleArr[12] = (byte)((this.end01) ? 1 : 0);
    ushort crc = CRC16(moduleArr, moduleArr.Length - 2);
    moduleArr[13] = (byte)(crc >> 8); moduleArr[14] = (byte)(crc & 0xff);
}

private void seatwLatch()
{
    if (debugRun) tlog("seat write param latch");
    seatwArr[5] = (byte)(seatControl % 3);
    ushort crc = CRC16(seatwArr, seatwArr.Length - 2);
    seatwArr[6] = (byte)(crc >> 8); seatwArr[7] = (byte)(crc & 0xff);
}

private void seatrLatch()
{
    ushort crc = CRC16(seatrArr, seatrArr.Length - 2);
    seatrArr[6] = (byte)(crc >> 8); seatrArr[7] = (byte)(crc & 0xff);
}

private void log(String txt)
{
    // Create a file to write to.
    if (debSrc == 1)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(debugPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(txt);
        }
    }
    else if (debSrc == 0) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(txt);
}

private void tlog(String txt)
{
    DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
    log(localDate.ToString("O") + ": " + txt);
}

private void tlog(byte[] arr, int size, byte dir)
{
    String s = (dir == 0) ? "out(" + size.ToString() + "): " : "in(" + size.ToString() + "): ";

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        s += "0x" + arr[i].ToString("X2") + " ";
    }
    tlog(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Отличный движок который имеет всего один поток. https://habr. com/post/342660/ Расширение UniRx решение всех проблем.

Comment: А с чего бы ему иметь 2 потока? Вы не совсем понимаете, как устроены игры, видимо. Создавать другие треды вам никто не запрещает, а unirx ничего принципиально не меняет.

Comment: в юнити нет многопоточности. при чем тут как устроены игры?

Comment: Наверное потому что Unity - это, в первую очередь, **игровой движок**, а игры изначально имеют ровно 1 главный поток? С физикой получается 2 потока, в который пользователю лезть не нужно, что по своей сути является фрейворком?

Comment: И да, в Unity есть многопоточность, никто не запрещает использовать [обычные треды](https://answers.unity.com/questions/180243/threading-in-unity.html) и с недавнего времени у юнити есть специальная система [job system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystemJobSystems.html).

Comment: через треды пробовали, никакой отправки нет на порт, но при этом в form если запустить тот же код, то отправка есть. вот про job system спасибо. забыл совсем

Comment: То, что у вас не работал код - не означает, что треды не работают. У unity единственное ограничение на этот счет - не использовать большую часть api в потоках, т.к. она не thread-safe, ну и с переносимостью могут быть проблемы, а так все работает.